Enable use of multiple comment templates in Staging Ground
On various occasions I found myself using more than one canned comment while reviewing a Staging Ground question (which is expected, since completely new users tend to make multiple mistakes). The flow would be to insert one, CTRL+A, CTRL+X, insert the second one and CTRL+V at the end (apply again if needed). This is not a big hindrance in any way, but those little things matter in a scale.
One solution would be to have checkboxes instead of radio buttons in the "Add feedback or comments" section. Can this change be implemented?

When doing that, it's probably better to use multiple comments anyway. See Prefer granular pieces of feedback to longer comments.

I recommend not implementing this feature, in my opinion when we want to leave feedback for multiple issues it is best to leave multiple comments in the Staging Ground.
Multiple comments allow us to utilize the nested comments feature of the Staging Ground better where the asker can ask us for guidance on specific comments more easily and we can have a dedicated comment chain for each issue that might be present in the question. This would allow the overall comment thread to be much more clear since we won't be discussing each issue in the same thread.
We also don't have any concerns about cluttering up the comment section since the posted comments won't get published to the main site when the question is approved.

Dedicated comment chain is very sensible for me, I did not take that into account. Thanks for feedback.

Also, in case reviewers want to post something "in between"/mixing two comment templates (assuming they belong together), copy-pasting the relevant parts might also be better than using both templates 1:1 after another.
